# Mongo Spring JPA giving IndexOutOfBoundsException in findAll() call

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-mongodb

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.bulkReadAndConvertDBRefMapIntoTarget(MappingMongoConverter.java:1447)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readMap(MappingMongoConverter.java:1047)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:225)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1408)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1355)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:952)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolverCallback.resolve(DefaultDbRefResolverCallback.java:61)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver.resolveDbRef(DefaultDbRefResolver.java:103)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readAssociation(MappingMongoConverter.java:358)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:319)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:292)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(M


---------------
```

> This is the calling of mongo jpa method

```
List<LegalDocument> legalDocumentList = legalDocumentRepository.findAll(Pageable.unpaged()).getContent();

-------------------------------------------------------------
```

> This code is showing the Repository

```
    @Repository
    public interface LegalDocumentRepository extends MongoRepository<LegalDocument, String> {

       @Override
       Page<LegalDocument> findAll(Pageable pageable);
   }
```

I was using this findAll() method from a very long. But now it is giving the IndexOutOfBound. Even i have so many methods available into repository. Please help me in fixing this.
Springboot 2.0.5 release and Mongo 4.2 Atlas

Comment: I suspect this issue is due to getContent not for findAll

Comment: Can you try extending like this `LegalDocumentRepository extends  PagingAndSortingRepository` and implement pagination?

Answer (score 0):

`MongoRepository` extends `PagingAndSortingRepository` and you don't need to write method in the repository remove it. Just call like this

```
Page<LegalDocument> legalDocuments = legalDocumentRepository.findAll(Pageable.unpaged());
```

And you are using `Pageable.unpaged()` that means you don't need pagination and use `getContent()` to get list. But you don't need do that, you can directly get list this way.

```
List<LegalDocument> legalDocumentList = legalDocumentRepository.findAll();
```

Comment: not working. can this be related to the version of Mongo spring jpa

Comment: Did you try 2nd one ? And it's working in latest version. Which version are you using now ?

Comment: legalDocumentRepository.findAll()
even this line is giving outofindex bound. i am surprised why this so